# Variable Values in Visual Studio Codes Outline (Python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Just found the "Outline" Tab in VSC for the first time:

[image]

Is there some way to take a look at all the listed variables values/content during running a Python script ?

Comment: Wut? The outline is like a table of contents, so you can quickly find stuff. It does *not* show values, much less runtime values. That’s the job of a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As deceze mentioned, you need a debugger instead to have a look at variable values during the running of a Python script. You can have a look [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_basic-debugging).

Make sure to add breakpoints (red dot markers) at points of the script where you want the execution to pause so you can check variable values.

Comment: Thanks for info. 
I hoped the outline was a simple way to avoid using the debug mode including breaks for monitoring the variables content ;)